# How to create a reusable button

Tags: xcode, object, button, subclass

I'm new to Xcode and objective c. I want to create a button (probably a UIBarButtonItem, for a navigation bar) with a particular appearance, which I will use repeatedly in different views. I've searched at length but can't figure out how.

Would it be appropriate to subclass UIBarButtonItem? I tried to do that, but I was quickly in over my head. Once I create the .h and .m files as a subclass of UIBarButtonItem, do I then have to instantiate a UIBarButtonItem? Do those files not automatically create a button object for me (imported from the parent class), which I can refer to as self? It seems like it would be weird to instantiate a button within its own subclass.

One thing I want to do is add the line,

`button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;`

but I'm at a loss as to how to create reusable button with that property.

Even if that is completely the wrong approach to creating a reusable custom button, I clearly need to improve my understanding of objects, so explanation of my misunderstandings would be much appreciated!

Please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this without subclassing - by making a category (a preferred way of doing things in Objective-C). With a category you can provide custom methods for an object without having to subclass it. You *can't* (easily) provide custom properties, but in your case this is not relevant.

*Using a Category*

This is how your category header file could look:

```
//  UIButton+StyledButton.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIButton (StyledButton)
- (void) styleButton; 
@end
```

Then in the implementation file:

```
//
//  UIButton+StyledButton.m
//

#import "UIButton+StyledButton.h"

@implementation UIButton (StyledButton)

- (void) styleButton {
    //style your button properties here
    self.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
}
```

('self' refers to the button object, which also acquires the custom methods you write in the category.)

To use it, `#import "UIButton+StyledButton.h"` then you can do this sort of thing...

```
on viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton* myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
    [myButton styleButton];
}
```

*Using a Subclass*

The subclassed equivalent would look something like this:

The header file...

```
//  MyCustomButton.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCustomButton : UIButton
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
@end
```

The implementation file...

```
//  MyCustomButton.m

#import "MyCustomButton.h"

@implementation MyCustomButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self styleButton];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self styleButton];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) styleButton {
    //style your button properties here
    self.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
}
```

You provide two init methods - `initWithFrame` is the method to call when alloc/initing the object in code; `initWithCoder` is the init method called by the system if loading the object from a storyboard or xib.

To create one of your custom buttons in code, you alloc/init as you would any other object:

```
MyCustomButton* button = [[MyCustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
```

You wouldn't also alloc/init the superclass instance, this is done by the `initWithFrame:` method in the subclass when it calls `[super initWithFrame:frame]`. `self` refers to your custom subclass instance, but that *includes* all of the (public) properties and methods from it's superclass - unless you have implemented overrides in the subclass.

To use your subclassed button  in a storyboard/xib, just drag out a regular button then set it's type to your custom button class in the Identity Inspector. The `initWithCoder` method is called automatically when the button is loaded from the storyboard/xib into a view.

*update*

From your comments, you seem to harbour a few confusions still, so here are some highly compressed de-obfuscating notes...

Keep away from subclassing UINavigationController unless you really know what you are doing. It's rarely necessary.

The buttons on a navController's interface are  properties of it's contained viewControllers. Look up the `navigationItem` property of `UIViewController` (similarly - in the case of a `UIToolbar` - the View Controller has a `toolbarItems` property). This allows Navigation Controllers to be context-aware.

The 'viewDidLoad' in my example is assumed to be in a regular `UIViewController`. My example is also a category on the regular `UIBUtton` which has *no formal relationship* with `UIBarButtonItem`.

Try getting a UIButton category to work with a regular ViewController first before experimenting with `UIBarButtonItem` (which does *not* inherit from `UIButton`).

`UIBarbuttonItem` has no `initWithFrame`, because the thing that organises the bar (`UINavigationBar` or `UIToolbar`) - in this case a Navigation Controller - is responsible for it's ultimate size and positioning. The viewController governs the relative order of barButtonItems, and whether they appear on the left or the right, and the content and (some aspects of) it's appearance,  but the rest is up to the NavController.

Comment: Thank you so much for this thorough explanation. It has led me to some more questions, if anyone has the patience to explain a few more things. (1) I couldn't quite get the category to work. I created the category files and added the viewDidLoad bit to a custom navigation controller. I changed the class of one of my navigation controls to my custom class. But I don't see a button appearing when I run. Was a UINavigationController the appropriate place to try to create the button?

Comment: (2) Is this not possible with a UIBarButtonItem instead of a UIButton? How come the former does not have an initWithFrame method? I thought the former inherited from the latter?

Comment: @mkc842... i've posted an update, i hope that helps and doesn't just add more confusion!

Comment: hey, thanks again for your help with that. i'm pretty clear on that now. after wavering a bit, i'm working full steam on understanding xCode. if you have time, i would greatly appreciate your expertise on my new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501270/how-to-display-various-view-controllers-each-having-its-respective-navigation-c