# Off by 20 pixels (y axis) when adding subview myNavigationController.view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a navigation controller with a menu button. When the menu button is pressed, the current view (complete with its navigation bar) should slide to the right, and a menu should simultaneously and contiguously slide in from the left. The details are explained in the comments in the code, below.

It works except in one regard. The current view (in this case, "Conversations"), when added back into the container view I implement, has to have its frame set to "y.min"=-20, or else there are 20 pixels above its navigation bar. However, when I set its y.min to -20, this shifts everything within its view up by 20 pixels. So when the menu button is pressed, everything in the current view suddenly jumps upwards by 20 pixels.

I can't figure out why this is happening or how to correct this. It is also possible that there's an easier way to go about all of this, but I'm not aware of one.* (*I'm not interested in third-party files. I want to learn to do this myself.)

Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction) showMenu:(id)sender
{

// get pointer to app delegate, which contains property for menu pointer
AppDelegate *appDelegate = getAppDelegate;

//create container view so that current view, along with its navigation bar, can be displayed alongside menu
UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 548.0f)];
[container setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

//before presenting menu, create pointer for current view, to be used in completion routine
UIView *presenter = self.navigationController.view;

//present menu's VC. it is necessary to present its (table) VC, not just add its view, to retain the functionality of its cells
[self presentViewController:appDelegate.menuVC animated:NO completion: ^{

    //obtain a pointer to the menu VC's view
    UIView *menuTemp = appDelegate.menuVC.view;

    //replace menu VC's view with the empty container view
    appDelegate.menuVC.view = container;

    //add the menu view to the container view and set its frame off screen
    [container addSubview:menuTemp];
    menuTemp.frame = CGRectMake(-260.0f, 0.0f, 260.0f, 548.0f);

    //add the the view that was displayed when the user pressed the menu button. set its frame to fill the screen as normal
    [appDelegate.menuVC.view addSubview:presenter];
    presenter.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 548.0f);

    //animate the 2 subviews that were just added; "PRESENTER"'S FRAME IS THE ISSUE
    [UIView animateWithDuration:25.3f delay:0.0f options:nil animations:^{
                         [menuTemp setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 260.0f, 548.0f)];
                         [presenter setFrame:CGRectMake(260.0f, -20.0/* or 0 */f, 320.0f, 548.0f)];
                     } completion:nil];

}];
}
```

Here is an illustration of my two options (click for higher resolution):
[image: visual]

screen 1) The first screen shows the view before clicking the menu button.

The next two screens show two possibilities as the menu transition animation begins.

screen 2) This is what the transition looks like when I set presenter.frame.y.min to -20. As you can see, the button in the view has jumped up by 20 pixels.

screen 3) This is what the transition looks like when I set presenter.frame.y.min to 0. As you can see, a bar 20 pixels tall is present at the top. The blue color indicates the container view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem some time ago when I didn't create my view controller tree correctly. My 20px off was caused by adding a `UINavigationController` view as a subview. I talked with the Apple Engineers in the labs at WWDC that year. They said I was using the navigation controller incorrectly, it needs to be a top level construct and you shouldn't put it in another `UIViewController`. That said you can put them in a container view controller like `UITabBarController` and `UISplitViewController`.

Your issue is not in the code you've posted it is in the architecture of your view controllers. I've uploaded a sample app to GitHub showing how to create a "Slide Menu" App like the FaceBook and StackOverflow iPhone Apps. See https://github.com/GayleDDS/TestNavBarOffBy20.git

The sample app uses a storyboard with Container Views in the root view controller to manage a UINavigationController (main view) and UITableViewController (menu view).

[image: Storyboard]

[image: Main View]  Now show Menu    [image: Slide for Menu]

See commit message cfb2efc for creation details. I started with the `Single View Application` template and you need to add the `QuartzCore` framework.

Comment: Yes, I figured that is the cause, but I don't know why it causes this effect or what's incorrect about it. And I  need to figure out how I can change my code to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: @mkc842 I expanded the answer and created a sample app on GitHub to demo what I think your trying to do. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful. I have studied your app and made sense of it. However, mine has a complication, in that I don't think I can use an embed segue for the actual VCs I want in the larger container, since they will vary. Instead I am trying to embed a dummy that then presents the VC I want to display at any given time. I will update my question to show where I'm getting stuck.

Comment: Okay... scratch the edit for now... I think what your answer indicates is that, in the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501270/how-to-display-various-view-controllers-each-having-its-respective-navigation-c , I have to use option 1 (tab bar controller) rather than option 2 when navigation controllers are involved.